# 2D array Seating Chart C++

Tags: c++

I am studying c++ and I need to make a seating chart program. This is not my code as I am studying it to see how each part works. I am interested in the seating chart. I have tried many different things to try and figure this out myself, I have come close, having the Full (*) mark in the right column but it is never in the correct row. 
If I choose seat # 1 and Row # 1 it makes the mark on the chart at seat and row #2.
 Again, I am not using this code, I just learn better when I test things and see how they all work. 
Here is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int Show_Menu();
void Show_Chart();
const char FULL = '*';
const char EMPTY = '#';
const int rows = 11;
const int columns = 10;
char map[rows][columns];
double price;
int total = 0;
int seat = 90;
int seat2 = 0;
int Quit = 1;

int main()
{
    const int Num_Rows = 11;
    double price[Num_Rows];
    int row2, column2, cost;
    int answer;

    //I have this blocked out as I am testing the chart only
/*  cout << "Please enter price for each row." << endl;

    for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++)
    {
        cout << "Row # " << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> price[count];

    }
*/  
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            map[i][j] = EMPTY;
    }
    int choice;
    do
    {
        choice = Show_Menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "View Seat Prices\n\n";

            for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++)
            {
                cout << "The price for row " << (count + 1) << ": ";
                cout << price[count] << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Purchase a Ticket\n\n";
            do
            {
                cout << "Please select the row you would like to sit in: ";
                cin >> row2;
                cout << "Please select the seat you would like to sit in: ";
                cin >> column2;
                if (map[row2][column2] == FULL)
                {
                    cout << "Sorry that seat is sold-out, Please select a new 
                             seat.";
                    cout << endl;
                }
            else
            {
                cost = price[row2] + 0;
                total = total + cost;
                cout << "That ticket costs: " << cost << endl;
                cout << "Confirm Purchase? Enter (1 = YES / 2 = NO)";
                cin >> answer;

            if (answer == 1)
            {
                cout << "Your ticket purchase has been confirmed."
                     << endl;
                map[row2][column2] = FULL;
            }
            else if (answer == 2)
            {
                cout << "Would you like to look at another seat? (1 =                    
                     YES / 2 = NO)";
                cout << endl;
                cin >> Quit;
                    }

                    cout << "Would you like to look at another seat?(1 = YES / 2 
                            = NO)";
                    cin >> Quit;
                }
            } while (Quit == 1);

            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "View Available Seats\n\n";
            Show_Chart();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Total ticket sales: " << total << ".\n\n";
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "quit\n";
            break;
        default: cout << "Error input\n";
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
    return 0;
}


int Show_Menu()
{
    int MenuChoice;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << " \tMAIN MENU\n";
    cout << " 1. View Seat Prices.\n";
    cout << " 2. Purchase a Ticket.\n";
    cout << " 3. View Available Seats.\n";
    cout << " 4. View Ticket Sales.\n";
    cout << " 5. Quit the program.\n";
    cout << "_____________________\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
    cin >> MenuChoice;
    cout << endl << endl;
    return MenuChoice;
}

void Show_Chart()
{

    cout << "Seats 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ";
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)//rows
    {
        cout << endl << "Row " << (row + 1);

        for (int columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++)
        {
            cout << " " << map[row][columns];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Please [edit] the question to make that clearer.  Also, try and reduce the code to a [mcve] (so you probably don't need all the prompts and input - just hard code some values).

Comment: My question was how to get the Full (*) mark in the right column as it was placing the mark in the wrong column when a ticket was purchased. It isn't my code to reduce, I was just running it to see how the different parts worked as a reference for a similar assignment for a seating chart I needed to create. However, the question was answered, thank you.

Comment: It is your question.  You must make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I choose seat # 1 and Row # 1 it makes the mark on the chart at
>   seat and row #2...

The problem is that arrays in C start with index `0`, so the left most seat has index `0`, not `1`. Thus, if you enter `1` into `row2`, and write `map[row2][column2] = FULL`, then actually the second seat is marked.

A simple fix would be to write `map[row2-1][column2-1]`; but make sure that the user must not enter value `0` then.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!